# Zend_Paginator and design problem, domain models

Tags: zend-framework, model, domain-model

I'm trying to design my application using fat model thin controller approach like described [by Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/202-Model-Infrastructure.html), [in zend quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) or [`Bill Karwin's blog note`](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2008/05/activerecord-does-not-suck.html) but currently I'm trying to implement pagination using `Zend_Paginator` and I have trouble since every example I found is based on model which simply extends `Zend_Db_Table`.

At this moment I'm using `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array` which contains array of models(range,not all records from database), only problem is that I cant set overall items count.

Can someone give me advice what approach is correct?
Should I write my custom Pagination adapter or maybe change actual design and use models based on zend_db_table?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array adapter was created for a situation when you have a huge array and you want to show only a portion of it. You have to set FULL array for that adapter to work as expected.

Best option for DB results would be adapter DbSelect and using Zend_Db_Select ;)